# Align nav content partially to left and right with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a Navbar and i am trying to align the some Links to Left and some to right. I tried it with two lists one with class "ms-auto" and "me-auto" but this did not worked (everything is always on the left, see picture). In a nutshell, I want to have the "Dropdown" Item on the right of the Navbar and the rest on the left.

[image: How it is currently looking]

```
 <nav class="navbar fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-nav position-fixed" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Company</a>

            <ul class="navbar nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Home/About" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Home/Contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar nav me-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>    
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a couple of divs to contain the logo with the left items. Then just some flex and margin classes.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-nav position-fixed d-flex flex-row w-100" id="navbarSupportedContent">
       <div class="d-flex ms-0"> 
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Company</a>

            <ul class="navbar nav">
                <li class="nav-item pe-2"><a href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item pe-2"><a href="/Home/About" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Home/Contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                
            </ul>
       </div>
        <div class="ms-auto me-0">
            <ul class="navbar nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>    
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and i did it using only margin rights (me-auto & me-0):

```
<ul class="navbar nav me-auto">...</ul>
<ul class="navbar nav me-0">...</ul>
```

To center the middle one just dont specify margins at middle ul:

```
<ul class="navbar nav">...</ul>
<ul class="navbar nav me-0">...</ul>
```